# Why small shapes tend to move left side when using Box2D JS?

Tags: javascript, box2d

I made a small example of Box2d JS. There are small ball objects (8 vertex ball). You can put the ball where you like.

The demo URL is http://nmi.jp/working/box2d/eight.html

I can't understand why the balls move left without any collisions. Does anyone can explain the reason?

Comment: Thanks for giving us your source code to help you with...

Answer (score 0):

何回か試していると、右にも転がりますよ。The shape is bouncing on one corner of the octagon, which does not always give a perfectly vertical collision response. It's hard to tell the edges of the octagon with such a small shape, but make the shape bigger and it should become obvious.

Comment: Yes, sometimes it turns right, but usually it turns left. I can understand the reason. Do you have any idea that correct the problem?

Comment: I think it's just the way the floating point calculations work. Values can get rounded off giving slightly different results. Technically, this is not a problem. If you bounced an octagon on its corner in real life I'm sure it would soon fall over one way or the other. The only way you could avoid this behavior is to use a true circle shape.

Comment: ありがとうございます、うすうすそう感じていました。 Thank you for your information. I know circle shape can avoid this problem, but circle shape seems not to be considered the friction value (on Box2d,) so I'm trying to make the circle shape with 8/16 vertex (the result is same on 16.)